# how to connect two grove 6-axis accelerometers in the same i2c bus?

Tags: arduino

I am using Grove 6-axis accelerometer and gyroscope based on LSM6DS3 chip. It is possible to have  two addresses (0x6A,0x6B) by setting the SDA line high or low as per LSM6DS3 datasheet but how to do that so that i can use two sensors at the same time in the same i2c bus?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the datasheet:

> The Slave ADdress (SAD) associated to the LSM6DS3 is 110101xb. The
>   SDO/SA0 pin can be used to modify the less significant bit of the
>   device address. If the **SDO/SA0** pin is connected to the supply voltage,
>   LSb is ‘1’ (address 1101011b); else if the SDO/SA0 pin is connected to
>   ground, the LSb value is ‘0’ (address 1101010b). This solution permits
>   to connect and address two different inertial modules to the same I2C
>   bus.
>   [Bolding mine]

So you select the slave address with the SD0/SA0 pin which is otherwise used for the SPI interface. Since you are not using SPI, you are free to tie it high or low to select the I2C address.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to @DoxyLover's answer, you can download the schematics from the [manufacturer's Wiki](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-6-Axis_AccelerometerAndGyroscope/).

[image]

Here you can see there is a solder jumper labeled J1 and it is normally connected to GND, but you *could* cut the trace between the middle pad and GND, and then make a solder blob to bridge the middle pad to 3.3V. Just make sure you don't end up with a bridge from GND to 3.3V or you'll let the smoke out.

To clarify, on the physical board pictured below, I believe the "solder jumper" that is represented as J1 in the schematic is the three vertically aligned pads within a white rectangle directly above the LMS6DS3 chip.

[image]

Comment: With J2 & J3 to the left, next to INT1.  You can sort of see the trace which must be cut.  Soldering 3.3V would make address 0x6b.

Comment: Adding to this answer, I can confirm this works. I scratched the track for the existing connection to ground. I then soldered the middle pin to the 3v3 pad. To clarify, the three pads together are the ones to focus on. Oriented the same way as the picture, scratch the connection between the two bottom pads. I advise you you a multimeter and do a continuity test to confirm the connection broken. Then solder the middle pad with the top pad. The address is now 0x6B.
They don't make it easy.